# Notification from OneSignal and link from Dynamic link blank page

Tags: flutter, onesignal, firebase-dynamic-links

Have you encountered the following problem with using OneSingnal and google dynamic link in IOS device, after pressing the notification link:
[image]

The url that is sent to OneSignal is working well when using it in a browser or whatsapp

Comment: The problem is still relevant. Have you found a solution to your problem yet?